# Unwanted translation of newline characters in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, newline

In PostgreSQL I have a number of views that contain somewhere in them the following SQL:

```
select replace(
  replace(details, E'\n\n', '</text></line><line><text>'||E'\n'),
  E'\n', '</text></line><line><text>'||E'\n')
from personal_details
```

This is used to replace newline characters in the data with `</text></line><line><text>` so I can get the output in the format I want, but that's neither here nor there really.

**The problem:**

When I add this SQL (via PhpPgAdmin) into the Definition of the View and save it Postgresql seems to translate the newline characters so that the View Definition now looks like this:

```
select replace(
      replace(details, '

'::text, '</text></line><line><text>'::text || '
'::text), '
'::text, '</text></line><line><text>'::text || '
'::text))
from personal_details
```

As you can see it is translating the `E'\n\n'` which I do not want it to do as it makes the View Definitions harder to understand and if someone were to see the translated SQL for the first time (if they wanted to make a change to the View for example) they may not understand what the View is doing, compared to the SQL I originally entered as the View Definition.

There may be an obvious solution I am overlooking? but how do I prevent it from doing this and will this be having any adverse effects on my Views?

Comment: When you select before replacing, the thing is interpolated too, no?

Comment: @Denis - Apologies, but I don't quite understand what you are asking? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid the answer is probably "no".

The `E'...'` form is just an alternative string-literal representation, so it's not preserved in the stored value.

Now, you could make a good argument that the string-presentation code in PostgreSQL should scan each string and look for likely escape characters. Then it could display the PostgreSQL-specific escape format instead. I can't see anything mentioned on the [todo list](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Todo) so it might be worth raising this question on one of the PostgreSQL mailing-lists (perhaps start with general rather than hackers) and see what people's feelings would be about a change like this.

Comment: It would be reasonable to bring this up on a mailing list.  I can see arguments against it, but it can't hurt to ask.

Comment: @PeterEisentraut - When I get a chance I shall do this and report back any outcomes, thanks